# Is it not possible to change the web code in client side permanently for client?

Tags: javascript, web, page-refresh, head, http-equiv

Please see image given below:

[image]

I've put the code `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">` in the head section. Then I pressed Clt+Enter. The page is refresh after 5 second and my added code removed. (My intention was to refresh review page after every 5 second automatically).

> > Is it not possible to change the web code in client side permanently for client?

Can you explain, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.
Each time you refresh the page you pull it from the server so any local modification get lost.

If you need to refresh a page each X seconds you can use a browser addon like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc)

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible, everything you do via debugger tool is volatile.
So as soon as you refresh the page, everything is gone

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible.You are making  changes to the local copy of the website that lives on your browser .The changes you make are valid only on your local file.They won't be reflected to the file on the server. This is why  when you change or add some code in a document when you refresh the page you will lose all the modifications/additions you made. On each refresh the browser requests the original file from the server(the file without the mods you made).

Comment: Thanks for explanation.